# sharing variables between client and server c#

Tags: c#, client-server, ipc

I have client and server applications.
The server counts the number of commands it receives from the client.
I wish to share this number with the client.

The client does not hold an instance of the server...

I have a dll which holds service functions, and is being used by both the server and the client.
So, I tried to use the `set` property to save that number on the server side, and then use the `get` property on the client side, to get the number.

I always get 0...

Here is my code:

**Server side:**

```
 private void clientReceived(Client sender, byte[] data)
 {
      try
      {
          Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
          {
              SharedDll.NumOfSentTests = 5;
          }
      }
 }
```

**Client side:**

```
private void clientReceived(Client sender, byte[] dataReceived)
{
     try
     {
         Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
         {
             m_numOfSentTests = SharedDll.NumOfSentTests;
         }
     }
}
```

**SharedDll**

```
public static int NumOfSentTests
{
    get { return SharedDll.m_numOfSentTests; }
    set { SharedDll.m_numOfSentTests = value; }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How are server and client communicating with each other? If they don't run in the same process, the shared DLL is not actually shared between them (in memory), so static values set in one process don't automatically appear in the other process.

Comment: how do your client and server communicate through them? You will have to send the info to the client in the same way (or have the client retrieve it from the server, if the server can't push info to the client)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two *different processes* that use the same DLL do *not* share any state. Each process has its own copy of the objects in the DLL.

You need to add another command to your server - one that returns the number of commands. The client can use this just like the other commands.